# EWS: Validation of the credentials of the service

Tags: exchangewebservices

Is there anyway to check or validate the username and password assigned to an exchange service before getting a url ?

In my program now , I create a new service and assigned username and password to it as follows

```
var service = new ExchangeService(exchangeVersion) { Credentials = new WebCredentials(userSmtp, password) };
service.AutodiscoverUrl(userSmtp, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

If there is something wrong with the credentials (e.g. wrong password), the exception will be 
**"Autodiscover service couldn't be located"**.

The problem with this method that it does not really specify the reason for not being able to bring the url. So is there any way that I can know why exactly I am unable to locate the the service? for example I would like to see an exception message saying that wrong username or password.

Can anyone help me with that ?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer @ https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/

```
You can test:
-Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync Connectivity Tests
-Microsoft Exchange Web Services Connectivity Tests
-Microsoft Office Outlook Connectivity Tests
-Internet Email Tests
```

Comment: It's a great resource, but the OP clearly is looking for something he can do programmatically.

Comment: By using it, you will get a complete breakdown of all issues within seconds. You can see if the autodiscover service is working or not, and can point you in the right direction to solving issues. If the username and password aren't going to change, there's not much use for making that check programatically, everytime the service runs. If you can see the credentials are correct, you can move on to other troubleshooting issues.

Comment: @sasfrog - Why do you mark this answer down? It answers - "The problem with this method that it does not really specify the reason for not being able to bring the url. So is there any way that I can know why exactly I am unable to locate the service? for example I would like to see an exception message saying that wrong username or password." - Emphasize "So is there ANY way that I can know why exactly I am unable to locate the service?", it will be much more difficult to get an exception message with as much  info as the Microsoft tests will provide.